# Errors caused by GLU include (GLEW)

Tags: c, opengl, include, glew, glu

I have an OpenGL C project which uses GLEW. When I compile in Windows with MinGW64, I get the following errors:

```
In file included from C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/glew.h:1204:0,
                 from ...

C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 void APIENTRY gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *tess,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                                                                                           ^
C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/glu.h:96:24: error: expected ')' before '*' token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUquadricErrorProc)(GLenum);
...
```

Here is the snippet of code which causes the errors in file GL/glew.h:1204:0

```
1199    #ifndef GLEW_NO_GLU
1200    /* this is where we can safely include GLU */
1201    #  if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
1202    #    include <OpenGL/glu.h>
1203    #  else
1204    #    include <GL/glu.h>
1205    #  endif
1206    #endif
```

Line 1204  being an include for GLU, though I don't know why I would want that, I do not use GLU in my project.
If I add the line `#define GLEW_NO_GLU` before this snippet of code, then it is skipped and GLU won't be included anymore. **Result: no more errors.** My program compiles and runs just fine.

Can someone explain what is happening? Why do I have to modify the GLEW header to make it work?

Comment: You don't have to modify anything, just compile with `-DGLEW_NO_GLU`. This looks like it provides optional features depending on `glu` and you don't need them (and don't have a compatible `glu.h` available)